# Templating Error in Underscore js

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

Hi I am trying to explore templating in Underscore.js

So far I created this template string:

```
  var student = "<% _.each(students, function(elem, index, list){ %>" +
    "<h1>" + "<%= elem.lastname %>" + " " + "<%= elem.firstname %>" + "</h1>" +
    "<br/> <h2>" + "<%= elem.school %>" + "</h2>" +
  "<% }); %>";
```

Then on my code I called it like this:

```
  function appendTemplateData(dataString) {
        let container = document.getElementById("container");
        container.innerHTML = container.innerHTML + dataString;
    }

 var result = _.template(student, students);
  appendTemplateData(result);
```

On this part:

```
var result = _.template(student, students);
```

my template variable is student while I have an external js file w/c is an array of objects with the ff info:

```
var students = [
    {
        "firstname": "Woody",
        "lastname" : "Johnson",
        "school" : "Bloc",
        "grade" : 12,
        "midterm_score": 75,
        "final_score": 85
    },
    {
        "firstname" : "Jerry",
        "lastname" : "Jones",
        "school" : "Hack Reactor",
        "grade" : 10,
        "midterm_score": 50,
        "final_score": 65
    }
];
```

Upon running my code it returns me this error:

```
function (n){return o.call(this,n,m)}
```

I am not sure what it means. Any help? Why is there an error like that? How can I fix it?

Comment: the correct call should be: _.template(student)(students), more like you compile the template then you call it...the function you get is compiled one, is not an error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the correct call should be: _.template(student)(students), more like you compile the template then you call it...the function you get is compiled one, is not an error

```js
 var student = "<% _.each(students, function(elem, index, list){ %>" +
    "<h1>" + "<%= elem.lastname %>" + " " + "<%= elem.firstname %>" + "</h1>" +
    "<br/> <h2>" + "<%= elem.school %>" + "</h2>" +
  "<% }); %>";
  
  var students = [
    {
        "firstname": "Woody",
        "lastname" : "Johnson",
        "school" : "Bloc",
        "grade" : 12,
        "midterm_score": 75,
        "final_score": 85
    },
    {
        "firstname" : "Jerry",
        "lastname" : "Jones",
        "school" : "Hack Reactor",
        "grade" : 10,
        "midterm_score": 50,
        "final_score": 65
    }
];

  function appendTemplateData(dataString) {
        let container = document.getElementById("container");
        container.innerHTML = container.innerHTML + dataString;
    }

 var compiledTemplated = _.template(student);
 var result = compiledTemplated({students: students});
  appendTemplateData(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>


<div id="container">
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! Quick question how does the (students) work? is it a function? I am a bit confuse calling the external js file with () parenthesis only. Please explain further

Comment: i edited to make the calls more easier and explicit...at first it was getting the students just from scope, so now am explicitly passing the the students and can see am passing it to the compiled template...more info here: http://underscorejs.org/#template